# C++ associative container (unordered_map) find and insert the same key at the same time from multiple threads

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I am aware of other similar questions regarding find and insert at the same time, my question is specific to find and insert the SAME KEY at the same time.

Per c++ 14 standard for containers requirements 23.2.5  "15. The insert and emplace members shall not affect the validity of iterators if (N+n) < z * B, where N is the
number of elements in the container prior to the insert operation, n is the number of elements inserted, B is the container’s bucket count, and z is the container’s maximum load factor.".

According to this requirement, if I use unordered_map's reserve method, to pre-allocate buckets, this should take care of most racing conditions. But what if you insert and find the SAME KEY at the same time from multiple threads?

Update: what I really mean is that will find read garbage when inserting at the same time?

Comment: Do you mean at the same time from two threads?

Comment: @ wally, Yes, from multiple threads. updated the question. thanks

Comment: Iterator validity does not imply thread safety. You cannot modify standard containers from multiple threads without syncrhonization.

Comment: If you are going to write to any STL container from multiple threads, you must protect it with a mutex.  The only time you don't need to do this is when all threads (including the main thread) only read.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [thread safety in std::map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29226578/thread-safety-in-stdmap)

Comment: Remember to make sure you've protected the entire transaction, not just the individual operations that make up the transaction, where necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I took some time to read the gcc implementation.

1. If one thread insert using

   unordered_map mp; 
   mp[key] = value;

   while one thread read using:
   auto it = mp.find(key);
   // then use it to access the key-value pair

   Then yes, using iterator returned by find() may get garbage, because this is what happened during mp[key] = value:

   1. operator[] dynamically create a node containing (empty_value)
   2. bucket pointers point to the newly created (empty_value) node.
   3. the "=" then put "value" in the newly created node.

   find(key) can read garbage after step 2 and before step 3 finishes.
2. If we use unordered_map::insert, then it will be different, because what happened is:

   1. Node containing (value) is dynamically created.
   2. bucket pointer points to the newly created node.

So when using find(key), either unordered_map cannot find the key-value pair, or the key-value pair has been fully created.

This is my understanding to the implementation. please correct me if I am wrong.